# How do you implement the new DocuSign OAuth2.0 SOBO using eSignature SDK?

Tags: oauth, jwt, docusignapi, legacy

I'm in the process of converting an internal C# API that uses a legacy SOBO integration to one that uses OAuth 2.0 as required by DocuSign.  The legacy application makes all requests to DocuSign using DocuSign credentials of an application user (a non-person) and injects SOBO data (email address) in the appropriate header when we need to generate an embedded sending URI and have it appear that the envelope was sent by a real person without using their credentials.

I have successfully converted another (non-SOBO) internal API using JWT grant, but I do not know how replicate the SOBO dependent workflow.  Have read Matt King's article "From the Trenches: OAuth 2.0 and the new SOBO", but still a bit confused.  I know how to extract userId from email address as mentioned in the article, but not sure what do with it.  Similar to my legacy application, I am using a application user to get consent and ask for JWT token without prompting internal users for their consent.  Is this still possible using OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to help here. Once you've retrieved the user's apiUserName / userId you'll want to add it into the JWT assertion's sub line.

When you go to generate the token, if consent has not been provided by or for the user, our system will send back an error of "Consent_Required." See https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent for different methods of granting consent.

For individual consent, the user needs to go to a specific URL containing your clientId, redirectUri, and some additional scopes. If they hadn't previously consented to the scopes in your OAuth request they will be prompted to do this *once*. You can confirm consent has been applied by having them visit the same link afterwards, which will send them directly to your redirectUri.

Domain consent works a little differently -- you need to have an organization, a claimed domain, and the users you're providing consent on behalf of need to have an email address that is part of that claimed domain.

Happy to connect and walk you through it -- if you can open a ticket at support.docusign.com and in the details request they reach out to me I should be able to have the case transferred and work with you from there.

Regards,

Matt King

Comment: My fault.  At some point in time I unknowingly switched clientId value with impersonationId value in the construction of my consent URI.  All works now.  Thanks.